# Non-bundle external fonts for iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, external

How to use non-bundle custom fonts in my iOS Application? I want to add font to app via iCloud or from internet and use it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this via

```
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont
```

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretext/1499499-ctfontmanagerregistergraphicsfon)

You only need a reference to a file or data reference. The code should be self-explained:

```
guard let fontData = NSData(contentsOfFile: pathForResourceString) else {
    fatalError("[UIFont] Could not get data of font")
}

guard let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: fontData) else {
    fatalError("[UIFont] Could not get dataprovider of font")
}

guard let fontRef = CGFont(dataProvider) else {
    fatalError("[UIFont] Could not create font")
}

var errorRef: Unmanaged<CFError>?
if CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(fontRef, &errorRef) == false {
    fatalError("[UIFont] Could not register font")
}
```

Then you can access the font over its name, like it were in the bundle.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for